# how to add a contacts to a particular group ? ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

Fetching contacts and creating group and pushing the contact inot group using group id is getting failed in ios

i check the Group exists already or not and create group if no available

```
-(void) CheckIfGroupExistWithName:(NSString*)groupName {


BOOL hasGroup = NO;
  //checks to see if the group is created ad creats group for contacts
// ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFIndex groupCount = ABAddressBookGetGroupCount(addressBook);
CFArrayRef groupLists= ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllGroups(addressBook);

for (int i=0; i<groupCount; i++) {
    ABRecordRef currentCheckedGroup = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groupLists, i);
    NSString *currentGroupName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(currentCheckedGroup);
    NSLog(@"GroupName= %@",groupName);
    if ([currentGroupName isEqualToString:groupName]){
        //!!! important - save groupID for later use
    groupId = ABRecordGetRecordID(currentCheckedGroup);
        NSLog(@"group id = %i",groupId);
        hasGroup=YES;
    }
}

if (hasGroup==NO){
    //id the group does not exist you can create one
    [self createNewGroup:groupName];
}

//CFRelease(currentCheckedGroup);
CFRelease(groupLists);
//CFRelease(addressBook);
```

}

get the contact details and tries to save by this way

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController  *)peoplePicker
    shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
    {


NSString *name = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

contactNameText.text=name;

ABMultiValueRef phones = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSString* mobile=@"";
mobile = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0);

contactNoText.text=mobile;
CFErrorRef error=NULL;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef ICEBUZZGroup = ABAddressBookGetGroupWithRecordID(addressBook, groupId);
BOOL didAdd = ABGroupAddMember(ICEBUZZGroup,person,&error);

 if (!didAdd) {
}


BOOL didSave = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);

if (!didSave) {
```

}

PLs help

Thank in advance

Comment: show us what you have tried thus far.

Comment: This question is not off topic... It needs some elaborate details like some code .... KSR pls provide some details